# READ COMMITTED or SERIALIZABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a practice and I don't know which is better, thanks for advice.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_ORDER(
    oid    IN NUMBER,
    ccode  IN VARCHAR,
    eid    IN NUMBER)
AS
    total CUSTOMER.TOTAL_ORDERS%TYPE;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES(oid, ccode, eid, sysdate, sysdate + 5, sysdate + 1,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    SELECT TOTAL_ORDERS
    INTO total
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE = ccode;

    total := total + 1;

    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET TOTAL_ORDERS = total
    WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE = ccode;

    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SQLERRM );
        ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Decided what isolation level the procedure INSERT_ORDER should be processed and to justify your decision.
You have the following two options: READ COMMITTED or SERIALIZABLE.

If you decide that the procedure can be processed at READ COMMITTED level then as
justification of your decision provide a proof that any concurrent processing of the
procedure at READ COMMITTED level does not corrupt a sample database.

If you decide that the procedure can be processed at SERIALIZABLE level then as a
justification provide a concurrent processing of the procedure at READ COMMITTED
level that corrupts a database.

Comment: what do you mean by corrupt ? a transaction does not corrupt anything, either serializable or read commited, it is only how they handle isolation level.

Comment: Assume that the procedure INSERT_ORDER can be processed
concurrently by many different users.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227898/whats-the-difference-between-read-committed-and-serializable-isolation-levels-i

Comment: I provided you an answer, feel free to comment your doubts on it

Comment: @RobertoHernandez I need some time to understand it fully, thank you very much. And why changing IS to AS

Answer (score 3):

1.READ COMMITTED isolation level: It's the default level. Each query(within transaction) could see only data committed before that query started. So, if you run the same query twice in the same transaction, you could see different results and phantoms, because other sessions could have altered the data.

2.SERIALIZABLE isolation level: Each query(within transaction) could see only data committed before that transaction started, plus changes made in the transaction itself.

Let's split the operations in your transaction:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES(oid, ccode, eid, sysdate, sysdate + 5, sysdate + 1,
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The first is inserting the data in the orders table, which depends on the input values provided by the procedure. You did not provide any description of this table regarding constraints or Primary Key. If Oid is OrderId, I guess it cannot be duplicated, therefore it cannot be called with different values.

The interesting part comes here:

```
SELECT TOTAL_ORDERS
INTO total
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE = ccode;
```

in READ COMMITTED that part is subject to phantom, because it could retrieve a different value of the one you expect if someone has make another order for the same customer at almost the same time. To avoid this, that you get the total orders of your customer at that moment in time no matter what happens in other sessions, use SERIALIZABLE.

Then finally you do

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET TOTAL_ORDERS = total
WHERE CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE = ccode;
```

Here applies the same rule. As you have calculated total with the value of the select before, in READ COMMITTED you would have the same issue as before.

For me here the important part is how important is the consistency of the data at the moment in time the UPDATE is done based on the SELECT INTO.

- If your answer is yes, I want the total to reflect the value at that moment in time no matter what happened in other sessions, use SERIALIZABLE
- If your answer is yes, I want that number to reflect the real value of the total in a multiuser environment at that moment in time, use READ COMMITTED.

Regards

Comment: Thank you and "If your answer is ....." miss yes or no?

Comment: Hi @user13862969 , if you consider the answer valid, please vote up or accept it. Really appreciated

Comment: and what if the answer is NO?

Comment: How can be the answer NO to both premises. Either you want the update to reflect the status of all orders, or you want to reflect only the status in your current transaction